# Laravel PDF reader

Tags: php, laravel

I have some problems how to show PDF in Laravel.
What I did is:
web.php

```
Route::get('/datenschutz', function() {
        $pdf = \PDF::loadView('pdf.Datenschutzerklarung');
       return $pdf->stream('Datenschutzerklarung.pdf');
    } )->name('getDatenschutzerklärung');
```

And I have that file in that folder, it loads great, but problem is, file is empty!
How I can post as HTML that pdf that I have?
I guess I have to convert that file in HTML, but I can't include third part 'pdf converters'.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Do you want to open a tab showing the PDF or include the PDF inside your HTML view?

Comment: I'm trying to convert pdf to html.

Comment: What is this `PDF` class?